# Define const as a variable

Tags: php

I looked up a few solutions, but nothing that's able to solve it. I realize that constants are not supposed to be modifiable hence the whole point of the word "constant".

In this case I'm dealing with an API class that goes like this

```
class GetAdGroups {

  const CAMPAIGN_ID = "";
```

I have to pass a value to CAMPAIGN_ID, but it can't be hard coded as a string.

So the following is not an option:

```
const CAMPAIGN_ID = 123;
```

I tried going with "define"

```
class GetAdGroups {
  $my_var = 123;
  define("CAMPAIGN_ID", "$my_var");
```

But it throws an error and when I define it outside the class scope, it also throws an error that the constant is not found.

Not sure what else to try. Pretty new to OOP and would appreciate your help

Comment: If something cannot be defined as constant - then it is __NOT__ constant.

Comment: i'm probably doing this backwards, how does the API expect to receive the value of that const? it means it has to be hardcoded?

Comment: Usually, you pass some data to API as array or some other structure. So, I don't know how constant is involved here. Why not just create class property?

Comment: I tried with just "public $CAMPAIGN_ID =" but it throws an error. Undefined class constant 'CAMPAIGN_ID'. It expects a constant, unless i'm completely lost.

Comment: Can you post your code on gist ?

Comment: What is the API you talk about? It's very unusual for API to require a constant.

Comment: @u_mulder he might be taking about assigning some api key, but incorrectly, I guess so.

Comment: no it's not an API key. It's definitely a variable that changes. It's Google Adwords API which is surprisingly notoriously badly made.. Here's the gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f08d8296e10d8df29ae8750d58748c4

Comment: If this is full class code - maybe you can modify it and use property instead of constant?

Comment: why try using a variable constant here, instead of just a variable , there is no need of constant here ?

Comment: @RobertSinclair check my answer now, you should use a different class you have missed the document .

Answer (score 1):

Check this [what are new features in php 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

```
<?php
const ONE = 1;
const TWO = ONE * 2;

class C {
    const THREE = TWO + 1;
    const ONE_THIRD = ONE / self::THREE;
    const SENTENCE = 'The value of THREE is '.self::THREE;

    public function f($a = ONE + self::THREE) {
        return $a;
    }
}

echo (new C)->f()."\n";
echo C::SENTENCE;
?>
```

this may help you. You can use expression as constant value here.

Note:-

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric
>   and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously
>   expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations
>   and default function arguments.

Yes, this is quite impossible, even you can not do like

```
function bar(){
    return 'Hi';
}
class C {
    const SENTENCE = bar();    
    //const SENTENCE = :SELF:foo();


    public static foo(){
        return "Hello';
    }
}
echo C::SENTENCE;
```

@u_mulder is very correct.

You have missed reading the documentation correctly.

```
/**
 * This example gets all ad groups in a campaign. To get campaigns, run
 * GetCampaigns.php.
 */
```

Check [this class](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201702/BasicOperations/GetCampaigns.php) instead.
here your campaign id is variable.

```
 foreach ($page->getEntries() as $campaign) {
          printf(
              "Campaign with ID %d and name '%s' was found.\n",
              $campaign->getId(),
              $campaign->getName()
          );
        }
```

Comment: These features mean that something is __earlier__ defined as constant. That's why it can be used in new constants. In OP question there's another situation.

Comment: unfortunately it's as u_mulder said, i can't use this. the value has to come from a variable, I can't calculate it with math expressions.

Comment: @u_mulder he has missed the documentation, there is another class for that. check the link I have provided :D

Comment: Hi, but I don't need the campaign IDs I already have them. I need the ad groups within the campaigns. So in your example $campaign->get()Name, I need to pass that as the const CAMPAIGN_ID

Comment: @RobertSinclair yes, according to your need you can implement that, I just thought, you missed an information, I should let you know.

Comment: thank you, i appreciate you looking into it. It's just badly made API, lots of people complaining about it. From setup, to documentation to usage in general it's a mess

Comment: please send pull request by what ever information, you can add because of your work, so that that will help the future users.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 7+ then you can use this way .

```
// Works as of PHP 7
define('ALLVAR', array(
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'bird'
));
echo ALLVAR[1]; // outputs "cat"
```

If you are using php < 7 Then use this way .

```
define ("ALLVAR", serialize (array ('dog','cat','bird')));


$my_const = unserialize(ALLVAR);
```

Inside your Class you can define a function for constants.  Like below

```
class  GetAdGroups{
    public $options = array(
        'app_id' => 'hello',
    );
    public function getConstant($key){
        return $this->options[$key];
    }
}

$a = new GetAdGroups();

print_r($a->getConstant('app_id'));
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is that it didn't allow me to use a public property like in your example it had a "const" in it, so if I would use the public property it would throw an error that 'constant is missing'. I had to a few lines of code so it accepts a class property instead of a const to make it work

Comment: Then , you can Use it 
 private static $options = array(
        'app_id' => 'hello',
    );

  and  

public static function getConstant($key){
        return self::$options[$key];
    } .   print_r(GetAdGroups::getConstant('app_id'));

Comment: yes, but it's still not passing a variable into a constant, we're still dealing with properties (private or public) :)